# Can't access JBoss AS 7 from remote machine

Tags: jboss7.x

I am running JBoss AS 7 on port 8080. I am able to access it from my local machine (`http://localhost:8080`). However I am not able to access it from another machine on the same network, e.g. `http://192.168.1.104:8080` does not work. I have disabled the Windows firewall on the local machine. In fact, if I start a Tomacat server on the local machine at port 8080 it is easily accessible from a remote machine. So it is something about the JBoss server that is causing the problem. Any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start the server with `-Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.104` option

OR

add the server IP address in your standalone.xml

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.1.104}"/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

You can use 0.0.0.0 instead of 192.168.1.104 if you want to bind to all IP addresses.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head! I am now able to access the JBoss server remotely. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 11):

If you are running JBoss from an IDE there should be a checkbox that allows for remote web access. It is unchecked by default. In eclipse, double click on JBoss under the servers tab and there should be a checkbox labeled "Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections." under the Server Behaviour tab.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
<interface name="public">
    <any-address/>
</interface>
```

It is necessary to restart server after adding this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are strating your server by executing run.bat, you should execure this command run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 (refer to https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss42FAQ)
If you start your server from eclipse, just tick the option (Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections) on the server behavior.